# MVC Routing - Redirect Unknown Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

We have a site which handles multiple customers, it's been setup in the past to configure the pages for that customer based on the route data value "customer"
The below route is an example:

```
routes.MapRoute("Customer", "{customer}", New With {.controller = "home", .customer = UrlParameter.Optional, .action = "Index"})
```

This means that the following URLs behave like this:
mysite.com/customer1  >  mysite.com/customer1/index
mysite.com/customer2  >  mysite.com/customer2/index

I would like to redirect any requests where the route data value "customer" does not equal "customer1" or "customer2" back to the root "mysite.com".

Is there a way to configure the routing table so that only "customer1" or "customer2" are valid paths and any others go to a different url?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller that handles the Customer action, return a redirect if you can't find the customer in the URL parameter

Comment: That's what I was thinking which I'll probably do, but there are loads of actions so I though it would be better to do it in one place rather than in every action.